# Do cables exist that will both charge via usb micro, but also function with a female usb port

Tags: usb, battery-life, tablet, charging, usb-hub

I have a tablet, in particular, a Hyundai Protocol x8.  The only port on it is a USB 2.0 micro type B port.
I can use a USB micro B to USB A Female adapter, then a USB hub, to plug in a keyboard, mouse, and other peripherals.
The problem arises that the tablet is then not charging, and is in fact, discharging a bit faster, as it is powering my mouse and keyboard.

Is there a solution or simple cable / hub anyone knows of, that would allow me to both charge the tablet, and have a USB hub?  Id like to plug it in more permanently and use it as a very basic self-contained desktop and monitor.

Comment: No, when the OTG port is in host mode, the power pin is an output rather than an input.  If you used a USB hub that has an external power supply, then the power draw from the tablet could be reduced.  But you cannot charge the tablet at the same time while in host mode.

Comment: Is that universal to absolutely every USB, or only Micro type B etc